# Has anyone tried to use a VGA monitor to the latest mac mini?

Tags: mac-mini, vga-adapter, dvi, vga

I recently purchased the latest mac mini (with an included HDMI to DVI-D connector). My monitor is VGA so I want to still utilize it. The problem is, Apple does not sell DVI-D to VGA adapter.

I'm looking at buying [one on ebay](http://www.ebay.ph/itm/DVI-D-VGA-Cable-Converter-Adapter-HDTV-LCD-TV-/280739294526?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item415d5dad3e). Is that the right adapter to use? Has anyone tried connecting the latest mac mini to a VGA monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use DVI-D as an interface? Your machine already has an HDMI and Thunderbolt port, and Apple recommends using a VGA adapter on the Thunderbolt port for that. See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4806?viewlocale=en_GB .

Comment: Wow, you saved my day! I have here a Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter and I never thought that would be applicable to this mac mini. Thanks a lot :)